# Google ignores "Range" header for HTTP GET?

Tags: node.js, header, range, google-cloud-storage, bluebird

I am using Google Cloud Storage XML API to download objects. As in the standard HTTP protocol and [as mentioned in Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download), I can specify a `Range` header to download just a specific range of an object. After trying several objects(files), the API always returns the complete data, which I'm trying to avoid in a single request. I'm using the request module (as promises with bluebird) on Node.js, so it looks like this:

```
var url = 'https://{bucket}.storage.googleapis.com/{object}'
        .replace( '{bucket}', this._bucket )
        .replace( '{object}', file.name );

var bearer = 'Bearer {t}'.replace( '{t}', this._token );
return request.getAsync( { url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': bearer,
                'Range': 'bytes=0-100',
            }
        })
```

The response data returns successfully, but not in the range I specified. It just return as a complete chunk of all the data. Am I missing something in the request configuration?

I'm afraid of a case where a content length of a file will be more then just a few kb's, which in this case can overflow the memory.

Comment: I think there might be a threshold when the object is too small to bother serving the range and will return the entire contents instead (which, by the way, is HTTP spec compliant). Can you try with a large object?

Comment: @jterrace I'm testing on a bucket that does not belong to me, so testing it with a large object is a problematic (the biggest file is about 75kb ). Is there a different way to test this? Also, I have searched on this subject in the HTTP spec and could not found the compliant description..

Comment: From section 14.35.2 - "A server MAY ignore the Range header."

Comment: Can you create your own bucket with a large object for testing?

Comment: Currently I can not. Except for this matter is there no reason for me to open a cloud storage paid bucket

Comment: You can try testing with the gs://pub bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624900/jterrace) noted, the server ignored my Ragne request since the object I pulled was less then the HTTP specification threshold. When testing it on larger objects (e.g. 3mb) it worked fine when requesting parts of the file. The returned content size is shown in the  `content-length` header.